# Chromecast Debug

Tags: android, google-chrome, chromecast

I have double checked chromecast serial number and the status show "ready for testing". When my android app sender connect to the chromecast, the chromecast show the Application Name, but x.x.x.x:9222 on Google Chrome is unable to start debug mode.
x.x.x.x refused to connect. 
ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Comment: Are you trying to connect when your app is running? Your app should be launched and running on chromecast for your debugger to be able to connect to it. Also make sure you reboot your chromecast once if you haven't done so after registering your device.

Comment: Yes. Phone is connected to chromcast and chromcast showing app name. I have reboot it more than once. But still unable to get debug mode.

Comment: Do you have any proxy setup on your network? If not, then try to contact our support to get further help (https://support.google.com/cast-developer/contact/google_cast_contact_us?hl=en&rd=1).

Comment: Did you find a solution to this problem?

Answer (score 1):

- Make sure all your devices(laptop, mobile device, chromecast) are connected to the same network
- Add your chromecast device's serial number in the developer portal< https://cast.google.com/u/1/publish/#/overview > (which you already did)
- Cast your video to the chromecast device
- Go to the following url in chrome browser< `chrome://inspect/#devices` >
- You will see your chromecast device and inspect below the url
- Click on inspect to debug your receiver application
- If the video is casting but you unable to find the device in chrome://inspect then it is probably because of your network. so try reconnecting your device to the network

Comment: How can I get the serial number? It's not written on the chromecast (at least there is no "S/N", I tried entering all the numbers I found in the dev console without success), and I don't see it in the device info on Google Home... I see the chromecast (and its IP) in chrome://inspect/#devices, but there is no more information and no "inspect" button.

Answer (score 0):

In the Chrome browser, enter the following in the address field to go to the Chrome inspector:

**chrome://inspect**

Add this line in your custom receiver to enable debug logs

```
cast.receiver.logger.setLevelValue(cast.receiver.LoggerLevel.DEBUG);
```

For more information on chromecast debugging you may refer to the following link

https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/debugging